# Using the same connection on AMPPS and MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, services, ampps

I am using **AMPPS 3.2** and **MySQL Workbench 5.2.31** on Windows 7.
I have installed MySQL as a service, running `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" install` in Administrator mode, and I have started it manually. It was successfully done because I can use PHPMyAdmin, and AMPPS shows MySQL working.

The problem is with MySQL Workbench. There is the same connection configured in it, but when I try to connect, the following error appears:

*Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306: Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: NO)*

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by selecting **MySQL Fabric Management Node** in ***Connection Method*** dropdown.

Click "Test Connection" button.